# Two structures inherit one trait, but with extra parameters

Tags: rust

How do I make two structures inherit one trait, but with extra parameters?

And I heard that doing so in Rust is not recommended. Why?

```
struct Foo {name: String,}
struct FooPlus {name: String, lvl: i128,}

trait Trait {
    fn show(&self);
    fn new(name: &str) -> Self;
    // fn new(name: &str, lvl: i128) -> Self;
}

impl Trait for Foo {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Self {}
    fn show(&self) {}
}

impl Trait for FooPlus {
    fn show(&self) {}
    fn new(name: &str, lvl: i128) -> Self {}
}
```

Comment: Traits define an API that's guaranteed for any type implementing the trait. That interface can't change depending on the type, or the trait would be unusable. What are you trying to accomplish with the trait? Like, why not just impl `fn new` on each struct instead?

Comment: @PitaJ I can do `fn new` on each struct, but for example I will start making a game, and I will have a `trait Unit` with basic characteristics: hp, damage, x, y. Logically everyone else should implementing it (bosses, players, animals). On another language I can implementing it and don't write code one same 10 times. And I wondered if it was possible to do something like in Rust.

Comment: If all of those fields are the same across units, consider aggregating them together. `struct BaseUnitStats { hp: i32, damage: i32, x: f32, y: f32 }` and have each unit have a `BaseUnitStats`. Then everybody takes the same constructor argument: that struct.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo Thanks! =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the extra parameter be an [associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/assoc_items/types.html) to the trait.

```
trait Trait {
  type ConstructParam
  fn show(&self);
  fn new(name: &str, arg: ConstructParam) -> Self;
}

impl Trait for Foo {
  type ConstructParam = ();
  fn show(&self) { ... }
  fn new(name: &str, arg: ()) -> Self { ... }
}

impl Trait for FooPlus {
  type ConstructParam = i128;
  fn show(&self) { ... }
  fn new(name: &str, arg: i128) -> Self { ... }
}
```

Note that you have to call the "no-argument" constructor with an extra unit argument, so `Foo::new("example name", ())`, but that unit argument is [zero-sized](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/vec/vec-zsts.html) and thus will almost certainly be optimized to nothing.

Though, as already mentioned in the comments, having `new` in a trait is odd. How often are you going to *polymorphically* call `new` on a type that's generic? If you really need to polymorphically generate instances, that sounds like an application of the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), not a good use for traits in this way. And if you're not doing it polymorphically, then just make `new` part of the `impl` for `Foo` and `FooPlus` separately.